# Recommended C++ Library Design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dll

I'm in the process of developing a C++ library providing different functions related to image/signal processing and other stuff. Its basically a development library for further use by developers. I want it to be as convenient and easy to use as possible. I have 3 different models in mind:

## Model 1:

A single large namespace containing all the functionalities of the library. e.g The C++ Standard Library is implemented inside the `namespace std`. Or OpenCV is implemented inside the `namespace cv`.

```
namespace library
{
    //all classes, variables, functions, datatypes are present inside this namespace
}
```

## Model 2:

A parent namespace, further subdivided into child namespaces according to functionality. e.g The .NET Framework's parent `namespace System` contains `namespace Collections`, `namespace Windows` etc...

```
namespace library
{
    //datatypes go here

    namespace group1
    {
       //functions related to group 1
    }

    namespace group2
    {
       //functions related to group 2
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

## Model 3:

Almost same as model 2, but containing functions as `static` members of classes instead of namespaces.

```
namespace library
{
   //datatypes go here

   class group1
   {
     public:
        static function1();
        static function2();
   }

   class group2
   {
     public:
        static function1();
        static function2();
   }
}
```

I need recommendation on which of these design model is best? Is there any other better approach?
Currently I am comfortable with the second model.

Comment: use whatever makes sense in your code (look at boost for example, there is no one standard, each library uses nested namespaces as necessary...) one thing I would say though is, use a namespace rather than a class to group functions...

Comment: I personally find the model 2 more intuitive, and lets me know faster where should I look if I need to find something in the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the functions can be used independently (it seems like it is, looking at your suggestions), and several functions can be grouped semantically, I'd absolutely choose the second option.

---

Option 1: to put everything in a single `namespace` would lead to adding too many different things, grouped into one single group.

Option 2: I find it a lot more intuitive than the others. As the library combines several totally different things, it seems like a good idea to group everything in groups and all of these groups to be a part of a big `namespace` with name - the name of the library.

Option 3: this options is almost the same as Option 2, but using `class` instead of `namespace` seems bad to me. The C++ standard gives you `namespace`s for this, use them.

---

But it really depends on the library, you're going to write. Honestly, choosing one of these options and later switching to another one will not be a big deal. So, you can start using one of these options and if the things get ugly and you see, that some of the other options will be a better choice - just do it.

---

Example: I have my own library, which implements wrappers for sockets, threads, IPC communication, etc. The structure I chose is exactly what you suggest in Option 2.